# Flexbox with absolutely positioned child does not expand

Tags: css

I have a flexbox and  a child absolutely positioned and centered.If i dont give height to my container its not displayed.Why its not expanding to its childs height automaticly?

```
<div style={{display:"flex",position:"relative",backgroundColor:"#f2f2f2", width: "100%"}}>
      <div  className="text">Some text</div>



</div>
```

css class text:

```
.text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;  
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

i am using absolute position because i need overlapping

Comment: When you use `position: absolute` you are taking the element out of the normal layout flow. This means the parents dimensions (height, to be exact) will collapse since it will think it has no content to flow with. Your only solution is to give the parent element an explicit height.

Comment: I am afraid what you are asking for is not possible. As said by @Terry absolute positioning takes the element out of the flow and from that moment on the flex positioning does not apply to it. On another note are you sure you need absolute positioning to achieve overlapping? Negative margins and/or flex-offset can work wonders!

Comment: thanks.i guessed that but now im sure

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `width: 100%` makes the element expand, although I'm not sure if this is what you need.

```css
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;position:relative; background-color: #f2f2f2; width: 100%">
  <div class="text">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using flex, then you can use `justify-content: center` to center your child elements within your flex element. No need to use `position: absolute` on your child element.

```
<div style={{display:"flex",justify-content:"center";backgroundColor:"#f2f2f2", width: "100%"}}>
```

I guess the curly brackets and the object is because you're adding Javascript code to the style somehow. I would rather just `css` classes for this, and add specific classes instead of inline style. Less messy code in the end.